# Load matrix matlab format with armadillo library problems

Tags: matlab, file-io, armadillo, mat-file, matlab-load

I've some problem if I try to load a matrix.mat <224x2 double> with Armadillo library:

mat A;

```
  A.load("matrix.mat");

  cout << " " << A.n_rows << " " << A.n_cols << "\n";
```

It prints:  5623 1

Can you tell me why?

Comment: Try to display `A`'s content to verify this.

Comment: How was matrix.mat created ?  Armadillo currently doesn't support reading binary matlab files. However, if you save matrix.mat in ascii format, Armadillo should be able to read it.

Comment: According to [this](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat), Armadillo does not support loading [binary MAT-file format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf). It just understands plain-text formatted files (produced in MATLAB using: `save out.txt A -ascii`)